# Preprocessing data in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

having looked at the kmeans example in the spark/example directory, I am trying to do K-means clustering on a set of latitude and longitude data. I have imported .csv data into a spark dataframe (~1M rows) and attempted to read the dataframe as an input to my k-means model however I keep getting an error.

My spark dataframe looks like:

```
 ID             col1           col2        Latitude         Longitude
ford            ...            ...           22.2             13.5
landrover       ...            ...           21.4             13.8
mercedes        ...            ...           21.8             14.1
bmw             ...            ...           28.9             18.0
...             ...            ...           ....             ....
```

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.read.csv('file.csv')

spark_rdd = df.rdd.sortByKey()
parsedData = spark_rdd.map(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x[3],x[4])).sortByKey()

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(parsedData)

sum_of_squared_errors = model.computeCost(parsedData)
    print str(sum_of_squared_errors)

centers = model.clusterCenters()

for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

The error I get is as follows:

---

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-76d5a466dc4c> in <module>()
      3 
      4 spark_rdd = df.rdd.sortByKey()
----> 5 parsedData = spark_rdd.map(lambda x: Vectors.dense(x[3],x[4])).sortByKey()
      6 

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in sortByKey(self, ascending, numPartitions, keyfunc)
    660         # the key-space into bins such that the bins have roughly the same
    661         # number of (key, value) pairs falling into them
--> 662         rddSize = self.count()
    663         if not rddSize:
    664             return self  # empty RDD

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in count(self)
   1039         3
   1040         """
-> 1041         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1042 
   1043     def stats(self):

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in sum(self)
   1030         6.0
   1031         """
-> 1032         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1033 
   1034     def count(self):

 ~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    904         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    905         # to the final reduce call
--> 906         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    907         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    908 

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 26.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 26.0 (TID 139, 10.3.1.31, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1752, in add_shuffle_key
    for k, v in iterator:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

**EDIT**: Thank you for you reply @Duf59 . Please note the dataframe has multiple data points for each ID (eg. 50 data points for 'landrover', 70 datapoints for 'bmw', 80 data points for 'mercedes' etc.

When I use your method, I get the following error:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-53-37fce322868d> in <module>()
          5 
          6 spark_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row["ID"], Vectors.dense(row["Latitude"],row["Longitude"])))
    ----> 7 feature_df = spark_rdd.toDF(["ID", "features"])
          8 feature_df.show()
          9 

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in toDF(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     55         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
     56         """
---> 57         return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     58 
     59     RDD.toDF = toDF

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    518 
    519         if isinstance(data, RDD):
--> 520             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    521         else:
    522             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in _createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
    358         """
    359         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 360             struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
    361             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    362             rdd = rdd.map(converter)

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in _inferSchema(self, rdd, samplingRatio)
    329         :return: :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType`
    330         """
--> 331         first = rdd.first()
    332         if not first:
    333             raise ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, "

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in first(self)
   1359         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1360         """
-> 1361         rs = self.take(1)
   1362         if rs:
   1363             return rs[0]

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1341 
   1342             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1343             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1344 
   1345             items += res

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    963         # SparkContext#runJob.
    964         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 965         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    966         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    967 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 134.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 134.0 (TID 557, 10.3.1.31, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<ipython-input-53-37fce322868d>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 790, in dense
    return DenseVector(elements)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 275, in __init__
    ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Latitude

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "<ipython-input-53-37fce322868d>", line 6, in <lambda>
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 790, in dense
    return DenseVector(elements)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 275, in __init__
    ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Latitude

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: I can also group my latitude and longitude into python lists by doing:
`lat = df.rdd.map(lambda y: y.latitude).collect()`
which gives: [lat1, lat2, lat3...]

or
`lat_lon = df.rdd.map(lambda x : [x.latitude, x.longitude]).collect()`
which gives: [[lat1,lon1],[lat2,lon2],[lat3,lon3]...]

This may be useful for an input to my k-model, but I'm not sure how

Comment: Note that the error is A) unrelated to k-means, but when loading the data, and B) on latitude and longitude, k-means produces bad results, because it cannot use Haversine distance.

Comment: Why do you call `sortByKey`?

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse I will be more careful next time when selecting tags.
What clustering method would you recommend for haversine distance?

Comment: Almost anything, except k-means and Gaussian Mixture Modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you apply `sortByKey()` to a RDD which is not a `PairwiseRDD` (`df.rdd` gives you a RDD of Rows, and in your case each Row has 5 values). `*byKey` methods operate on `PairwiseRDDs`, that is RDD which contains tuples of length 2 or other structure which can be unpack like `k, v = pair`.

Apart from that, you are trying to use ml algorithm with RDD. You should feed the kmean model with a dataframe here (by default, `kmeans.fit` expects a dataframe with a column named `features`). You can lookup the doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans).

What you can do is :

```
spark_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row["ID"], Vectors.dense(row["Latitude"],row["Longitude"])))
feature_df = spark_rdd.toDF(["ID", "features"])

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(feature_df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Duf59 . Please could you check my 'edit' on the original post to see what happened when I implemented your code, as it now returns a different error. Cheers.

Comment: Probably something to do with your data, what does df.printSchema() gives ? If Latitude / Longitude columns are strings, then convert them to floats first.

Comment: When I do df.prinSchema() it gives me:

    root
     |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
     |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
     |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Latitude: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Longitude: string (nullable = true)

Do you mean convert all the values in each column into floats? Or convert the column name into float? How would I do that? Thanks

Comment: Use something like `df.withColumn("Latitude",col("Latitude").cast('float')).withColumn("Longitude",col("Longitude").cast('float')).rdd .....` Then if it fails converting your Lat/Lon columns to float you should check your data, maybe your input contains some empty strings or other characters which can't be coerced to numbers.

Comment: Do you know how I can filter out any rows which do not contain floats? for example if a value in Latitude was 'foo' then how would I discard that row? using maybe df.filter()? Thanks for your help.
I have a post about it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950532