# Pyspark - ValueError: could not convert string to float / invalid literal for float()

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, k-means

I am trying to use data from a spark dataframe as the input for my k-means model. However I keep getting errors. (Check section after code)

My spark dataframe and looks like this (and has around 1M rows):

```
ID            col1           col2        Latitude         Longitude
13            ...            ...           22.2             13.5
62            ...            ...           21.4             13.8
24            ...            ...           21.8             14.1
71            ...            ...           28.9             18.0
...           ...            ...           ....             ....
```

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans 
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors


df = spark.read.csv("file.csv")

spark_rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row["ID"], Vectors.dense(row["Latitude"],row["Longitude"])))
feature_df = spark_rdd.toDF(["ID", "features"])    

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(feature_df)

sum_of_square_error = model.computeCost(feature_df)
    print str(sum_of_square_error)

centers = model.clusterCenters()

for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

However, I get the error:

---

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-f50a6cbe7243> in <module>()
      7 
      8 kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
----> 9 model = kmeans.fit(feature_df)
     10 
     11 

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    234 
    235     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 236         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    237         return self._create_model(java_model)
    238 

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    231         """
    232         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 233         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    234 
    235     def _fit(self, dataset):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3552.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 457.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 457.0 (TID 2308, 10.3.1.31, executor 1): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-145-f50a6cbe7243>", line 4, in <lambda>
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 790, in dense
    return DenseVector(elements)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 275, in __init__
    ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: GOLF


    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeSample$1.apply(RDD.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.takeSample(RDD.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.initKMeansParallel(KMeans.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.runAlgorithm(KMeans.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans.run(KMeans.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:319)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-145-f50a6cbe7243>", line 4, in <lambda>
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 790, in dense
    return DenseVector(elements)
  File "~/Downloads/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/linalg/__init__.py", line 275, in __init__
    ar = np.array(ar, dtype=np.float64)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: GOLFE 

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:957)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:888)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:948)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

The strange thing is that the error is different every time I run it. The 3 types of errors I get are:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode characters in position 3-5: invalid decimal Unicode string`

`invalid literal for float(): 2017-04`

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: GOLF`

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think some value of data in the columns may be incorrect (eg. occasional strings inside latitude and longitude column)

Is there a way to check if the value in each row of 'Latitude' is in fact a float? Is there a way to check if the value in each row of 'ID' is an integer?
I would like to discard the rows which contain values of the incorrect data type. Perhaps there a way of doing this using `df.filter()`?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.

UPDATE: I even tried `df.describe('ID', 'Latitude', 'Longitude').show()` and it returns numeric values for count, mean, stddev, min, max values for each column, indicating to me that they must all be numbers..?

Answer (score 0):

you should maybe have continued on the same thread since it's the same problem. For reference : [Preprocessing data in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922441/preprocessing-data-in-pyspark/44927398#44927398)

Here you need to convert `Latitude` / `Longitude` to float and remove null values with `dropna` before injecting the data in Kmean, because it seems these columns contain some strings that cannot be cast to a numeric value, so preprocess `df` with something like :

```
df2 = (df
       .withColumn("Latitude", col("Latitude").cast("float"))
       .withColumn("Longitude", col("Longitude").cast("float"))
       .dropna()
       )

spark_rdd = df2.rdd ...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I dropped null values and converted to float as you suggested. However I get the error: `"Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o440.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition"` - I've looked online and it suggests an issue with the 'zip()' command but I am not using the zip() command anywhere in my code? So I do not understand this error. I have also tried dropping the ID column so that I am injecting a dataframe with only 1 column named 'features' filled with dense vectors. Still same error.